# How to check if table is made in Jtable and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

Hi I want to check if table is made to add rows.If is not I want to show message :create table first. My problem : I do not know what I should type to if statement to check if is although one row made(which can suggest me that table was created).

I create table via NetBeans JFrame options this way:

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
           /*
           space is empty here because on start I do not create any rows.
           user has to click button create or add rows. 
                                                                       */
            },
            new String [] {
                "Name", "Surname"
            }
        ));
```

My if statment:

```
 if(//do not know what type here because new Object [][] will not work){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Create table!");
        }else //add row to table because exist {
        Object[][] temp = new Object[data.length + 1][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                temp[i][j] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
        data = temp;
        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using NetBeans GUI builder. If you go to the properties pane (the tab to the very right in Netbeans design view) with the `jTable` highlighted, you will see a property `model`

- Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button to the right of the property, and a Dialog will pop up
- Set the number of rows to 0, and the number of columns to how many columns you want, and set the column `title` and `type` and if you want it `editable`

Then in your `actionPerformed`, however you get the data for rows, add an array of that data to the model with `model.addRow()`

```
 public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     // get row data, and put it into an array
     Object[] row = {data1, data2, data3 ...};
     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
     model.addRow(row);
 }
```

So whenever the button is pressed, a row will be added dynamically to your table. That's the easiest way to do it with GUI Builder

**EDIT**

If you want to check the number of rows then you check the `rowCount`

```
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

 if (model.getRowCount() < 1) {
     do something.
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I know that. I only want to know what I shoul type to my if statment to check if the table is created(although  has one row). I know how to create table now I want to add something special, make the table more "smart"-the table has to know if is created. Is not? so can not add rows.

Comment: You mean you want to check how many rows the table currently has?

Comment: I don't understand the point of checking if the table was created. I might be misunderstanding you

Comment: Ok I have table created and I know how to create table. I have 2 buttons. First create table when you push it (the table is created with 1 row inside). Second add rows(one row by push). This is how it works. Now I want to add something special,make it better. So I decided to not add rows by every push button add but first if statment will check if is although one row. I want to eliminate this situation: you open frame with table and by add button create table row by row. on start my table has not any rows only name of columns. I hope you undestand me now :)

Comment: See my **EDIT**. Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: You question still does not make any sense though. The table is automatically created for you by NetBeans, so to check if it is created makes no sense to me.

Comment: "You question still does not make any sense though. The table is automatically created for you by NetBeans, so to check if it is created makes no sense to me." Yes that true but on start i do not make any rows. I want to see if user made any if he did he can use add row button if he did not he has to push create table first :)